# How I can I prove that the function $F:M(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M(n,\mathbb{R}):X\mapsto XAX$ for $A \in M(n,\mathbb{R})$ is $C^1$?

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces, differential

How I can I prove that the function $F:M(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M(n,\mathbb{R}):X\mapsto XAX$ for $A \in M(n,\mathbb{R})$ is $C^1$?

I think I have to do it by proving that the function $X\mapsto D_XF$ is continuous, but the thing is this question is part of a bigger question and this is the very first point of the exercise, whilst the second is to calculate its differential, so it doesn't make sense for me to calculate its differential here. Maybe I can somehow upperboud the norm operator of $D_XF$ without calculating it?

However, I was able to calculate that $D_XF:H\mapsto XAH+HAX$

Comment: It's a polynomial. Polynomials are $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Is $X \mapsto XAX$ a polynomial? It isn't of the form $\alpha_n X^n+...+\alpha_1 X+\alpha_0$

Comment: I mean that its components are polynomials (in the usual sense) in the $n^2$ entries of $X$. But it's also true that any expression you get from multiplying a bunch of matrices together (a "noncommutative polynomial" in a bunch of matrices) is also a polynomial in this sense, so the two possible interpretations of "polynomial" are consistent here. This boils down to the fact that matrix multiplication is a polynomial function.

Comment: $F=G\circ\Delta$ where $\Delta(X)=(X,X)$ and $G(X,Y)=XAY$. $G$ is bilinear and $\Delta$ linear, and (by finiteness of the dimension) they are continuous, hence they are $C^\infty$. Moreover, $D_X\Delta=\Delta$ and $D_{(X,Y)}G(H,K)=G(X,K)+G(H,Y)$, whence your $D_XF(H)$.